# duty and custom charges on Lens shipping to different country

Tags: equipment-recommendation, publishing

If a purchase a Lens from USA amazon and ship it to India, how much custom and duty chanrges will come

Comment: Go to the Amazon website, add a lens to your shopping cart, then click Checkout.  Put in a delivery address etc. and it will display the shipping charges. You can then cancel out of the process. Most of their camera gear says "This item is also available for shipping to select countries outside the U.S."  so you'd have to check with them if India is one of those countries.

Comment: For the mods, I'm not sure this is strictly(although I provided one for anish) a photography question, is there a better place to put this?

Comment: You should check with the customs office in your country.

Answer (score 1):

Ok here's what I understand for duty and custom charges.
When you order overseas it gets sent to your country it will go through customs who will then determine whether customs duty will apply. I think in most cases the buyer will have to foot out the bill unless Amazon does it for you. Where I'm from there's 0% tax on photographic equipment so custom duty does not apply for me.

For India it seems like it's a different case and customs and duty does apply:

- Basic Duty = 10%
- CVD = 12%
- SPL.CVD = 4%

There's a little link [here](http://www.cybex.in/indian-custom-duty/Lenses-Prisms-Mirrors-Optical-Elements-Hs-Code-9002.aspx) with a calculator that mentions this (although how current the rates are I'm not sure).

You might want to consider a local purchase even though it may be a little higher if you consider the hassle of going to clear your imports at customs.